# How would I simplify this case to just compact all the true booleans

Tags: java

I don't know how to simplify all the true statements to maybe a single one, if that even is possibly

```
case 1 -> {
              Image1.setVisible(true);
              Image2.setVisible(true);
              Image3.setVisible(true);
              Image4.setVisible(true);
              Image5.setVisible(true);
              Image6.setVisible(true);
              Image7.setVisible(true);
              Image8.setVisible(true);
              Image9.setVisible(true);
              Image10.setVisible(true);
           }
```

Comment: If you have variable names with numeric suffixes you probably wanted a list.

Comment: … and then you can have a `setAllVisible()` method

Comment: Use a List for sure

Answer (score 2):

One way can be to put all your variables in a list and iterate over it:

```java
List<PsuedoImage> images = Arrays.asList(Image1, ..., Image2);
images.foreach(i -> i.setVisible(true));
```

*(Pseudo-code)*

It's hard to give better options without more context.

Comment: I added the <>'s even though we don't know the type it's probably better than using a raw type.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer (imo) has been given by [@GaëlJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68320860/1552534).  But if you wanted to make this more general to do something with a common value for a list of objects, you could write a method that accepts a `List`, `BiConsumer`, and `value`.

Then you could call it like this (assuming the image was in a JPanel).

```
applyToAll(images, JPanel::setVisible, true);        
applyToAll(images, JPanel::setVisible, false);
```

here is a more visual example.

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = List.of(
         new ArrayList<>(List.of(1)),
         new ArrayList<>(List.of(1)),
         new ArrayList<>(List.of(1)));
         
lists.forEach(System.out::println);
applyToAll(lists, List::add, 10);
lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
[1, 10]
[1, 10]
[1, 10]
```

Here is the method.

```
public static <T, R> void applyToAll(List<T> list,
    BiConsumer<T, R> con, R argToApply) {
    list.forEach(type -> con.accept(type, argToApply));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Image> images = Arrays.asList(Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4, Image5, Image6, Image7, Image8, Image9, Image10);


static void setAllVisible(ArrayList<Image> images) {

    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {

        images.get(i).setVisible(true);

    }}
```

Something like this i guess and then use the setAllVisible() method in the case u want.